# Pairwise comparisons of two multivariate linear models

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, post-hoc

Currently working on a project that involves looking at aggression rates towards a variety of different objects in six primate species. I've created two linear models:

modelagg <- lm(log(Aggression + 1) ~ Obs_species + Object + Obs_id + Presentation_num + Group_size, data = New_data)

modelagg1<- lm(log(Aggression + 1) ~ Obs_species * Object + Obs_id + Presentation_num + Group_size, data = New_data)

and have used an ANOVA to compare:

anova(modelagg, modelagg1)

which found there is a significant difference. However, I want to find out where these differences are. What post-hoc tests would be appropriate here? Thanks!

Comment: By significant difference, do you mean that modelagg1 had a significantly lower residual sum of squares?

Comment: Here's the results of the ANOVA:                                                                               Model 1: log(Aggression + 1) ~ Obs_species + Object + Obs_id + Presentation_num + 
    Group_size
Model 2: log(Aggression + 1) ~ Obs_species * Object + Obs_id + Presentation_num + 
    Group_size
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1     59 51.717                              
2     44 30.607 15     21.11 2.0231 0.03552 *

Comment: The ANOVA results show that the model with an interaction between Obs_species and Object fits significantly better than the model without an interaction.